# ‘decorated’ or ‘painted’, which is better?

Tags: word-choice

The walls of the ancient Egyptian tomb were painted/decorated with beautiful paintings.

‘painted’ or ‘decorated’, which is better, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Of those options decorated would sound better, as using two words beginning "paint" so close together is very clunky. In general, try to avoid repeating the same word multiple times, especially within a single sentence.